# How to increase the width of my twitter feed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to increase the width of the twitter feed displayed on my webpage, I added a Div id to it and tried increasing its size in css however it stops getting bigger after a certain point, Also I want to add images in my portfolio section which includes 3 random pictures of like computers which get bigger and change size when you hover over them in css, how do I do this? Also I can't figure out how to change the color of the background of the webpage, everything I have tried doesn't work. Thanks.

I have provided the HTML, CSS and JS code for my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Muhammed's Webpage</title>

    <style>
        #body {
            margin: auto;
            max-width: 85%;
            font-family: 'Exo 2', Times, serif;
            color: black;
            padding-top: 50px;
        }

        .mainlogo {
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 900;
            font-family: 'Montserrat', Times, serif;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        nav {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            margin-left: 4%;
            opacity: 0.8;
            max-width: 85%;

        }

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: white;
            position: fixed;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        li {
            float: left;
            border-right: 2px solid black;
        }

        li:first-child {
            border-left: 2px solid black;
        }

        li a {
            display: inline-block;
            color: black;
            text-align: justify;
            padding: 36px 40px;
            text-decoration: underline;
            font-family: 'Montserrat', Times, serif;
            text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #aaa;
        }

        li a:hover {
            background-color: #C2E5E5;
            color: black;
        }

        .yt {
            margin-left: 53px;
            margin-top: 30px;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 500px;
            width: 650px;
        }

        #twitter {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
        }

        .contentbox {
            font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 2em;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            background-color: #C2E5E5;
        }

        .content {
            background-color: #C2E5E5;
        }

        p {
            text-indent: 3%;
            margin: auto;
            max-width: 95%;
        }

        .contentbox {
            font-family: 'Montserrat', Times, serif;
            font-size: 28px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        !function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
            if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mainlogo">

    <div>Muhammed's
        <br>Webpage
    </div>

</div>

<div id="body">

    <nav>
        <ul>

            <li><a href="#BasicInfo"> BASIC INFORMATION </a></li>
            <li><a href="#CurriculumVitae"> CURRICULUM VITAE </a></li>
            <li><a href="#Portfolio"> PORTFOLIO </a></li>
            <li><a href="#Report"> REPORT </a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="yt">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/nKIu9yen5nc">
        </iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="twitter">
        <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/applenws" data-widget-id="674678491141570560">Tweets by
            @applenws</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content" id="Basic Information">
        <h3 class="contentbox"><u>Basic Information</u></h3>
        <p>
            <br>Name: Muhammed Hussain
            <br>Age: 18
            <br>Contact Number: 07711909673
            <br>E-mail: Mhuss055@gold.ac.uk
            <br>Occupation: Student of Goldsmiths, University of London
            <br>Hobbies & Interests: Playing on my ps4 and outdoor tennis
            <br>
            <br>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content" id="Curriculum Vitae">
        <h3 class="contentbox"><u>Curriculum Vitae</u></h3>
        <p>
            <br><u>Jun 2015 - Currently Employed</u> : <b>Harrods - Operations Assistant</b>
            <br>Responsible for ensuring all daily administrative tasks are met within time schedule
            <br>Worked with colleagues to sustain a world class service of luxury goods, through providing an excellent
            service while working in a team environment and focusing on customer service
            <br>Proactive use of CCA and SAP software on a regular basis, in order to deal with online orders.
            <br>
            <br><u>Jun 2014 - Sep 2014</u> : <b>Direct Accountancy - Accounts Assistant</b>
            <br>Assisted Account Manager through creating invoices and sending to customers using SAGE software
            <br>Made and arranged invoices occasionally for customers, and ensured these were sent out promptly upon
            receiving the order.
            <br>
            <br>
            <u>Skills Gained:</u>
            <br>Communication - Established rapport and resolved queries within pressurised customer service
            environments
            <br>Teamwork - Motivated and developed colleagues to work effectively
            <br>Leadership - Showed leadership qualities when delivering end of unit presentations at Sixth form
            <br>
            <br>
        <p>
    </div>

    <div class="content" id="Portfolio">
        <h3 class="contentbox"><u>Portfolio</u></h3>
        <p>
            <br>Here im going to include some images and use css to make them interactive and exciting
            <br>
            <br>
        </p>
    </div>


    <div class="content" id="Report">
        <h3 class="contentbox"><u>Report</u></h3>
        <p>
            <br>Here im going to state why i did what i did in detail
        <p>
            <br>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your Twitter feed has a width set in HTML property. Erase the property and move it to CSS. That should fix the Twitter thing. **Edit:** Remember that the height is set on `Twitter > Settings > Widget > Height`.

**- EDIT 1 -**

Now that I know your Twitter feed can't be controlled by you, you have to control the result of your Twitter script which will normally be 600px of height by default. No matter what this is, you know it will end up styling an iframe with the `twitter-timeline` CSS class, so you only need to overwrite the value like this:

```
.twitter-timeline {
    height: 503px; // 503 because for some reason it needs 3 more pixels to catch up with your video, as I could see.
}
```

**- END EDIT 1 -**

2. You just gave away all of your personal information to strangers around the web. You'll probably be spammed in a few seconds if they are true. I suggest you **ONLY** provide necessary code. There is a lot of CSS and HTML not related to the question, you can simply ask them in another question or explain them apart of each other.
3. To place pictures you can do many things, being them random means either JavaScript or preloaded with PHP. I imagine you would be loading them from your site, let's say `/images/computers/` and give them a class, for instance `photo`. Then on CSS, you can do the following:

   ```
   .photo {
       height:200px;
   }
   .photo:hover {
       height:400px;
   }
   ```

That will make it bigger on hover using CSS. If you like to animate it, you might want to use other CSS properties. Search on the web, you'll find them.

**- EDIT 2 -**

So, looking at your pictures with the class `photo`, I see that you were not adding the `%` values correctly. You need to find a balanced value for each one of your images. In your case, we are playing with image `padding`, `margin` and `width` basically. So there are 3 images and you know that the percentage must reach something around 100%:

```
.photo {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em 0.15em rgba(00, 00, 00, 0.35);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em 0.15em rgba(00, 00, 00, 0.35);
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
```

According to this code I wrote for you, now the formula is:

(3 * 25%) + (6 * 1%) + (3 * 5%) = 75% + 6% + 15% = **96%**

6 times 1% because the padding will be added to both left and right of the picture.

**- END EDIT 2 -**

4. The background color of the website? That is just too basic. It depends on your needs, you can set your background color to the `<html>` or `<body>`. I'll use HTML:

   ```
    html {
        background-color:red;
    }
   ```

With that, your website will have a red background. Of course you can use HEX, or rgb() or rgba() or color names, whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the advice mate, everything works apart from the fact when i tried defining the height and width property for my twitter feed in css it now won't reduce in height no matter how small i make it, this is now the css code for the twitter feed:

#twitter {
  display:inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
}

Comment: @m.hussain easy! Twitter feed's (call it by its name: widget) height is set on Twitter! You need to go to your Settings > Widget and change the height right there!

Comment: sorry I'm confused, i would've thought the widget should change size if i define its size in css but it's height isn't reducing now, so how do i reduce it?

Comment: @m.hussain Ok. So I don't like Twitter's approach either, but it is that way. If you really wish to overwrite whatever Twitter makes your widget's height to be, you need to add `!important` after your CSS height. I mean like this; `#twitter { height: 300px !important; }`. Try it out. But the proper way should be to go to Twitter's website and change the height on your widget's editor.

Comment: @m.hussain to place pictures on the same line, use CSS `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` depending on your needs. Add this to all the elements you want to display in the same line.

Comment: It didn't make any difference mate, just to confirm:

#twitter {
  display:inline-block;
  height: 500px !important;
  width: 400px;
}

Comment: @m.hussain Add `display: inline-block;` to the YouTube class as well. Like `.yt { display:inline-block; }`. If `inline-block` doesn't fit your needs, try `inline`. You might end up using `vertical-align` CSS property too, but we can discuss that later.

Comment: I was already using display: inline-block on both my video and widget.

Comment: @m.hussain Did you try inline? Also, remember that even this way, if the YouTube video width + widget width add up wider than your page, it will **always** send one of them down. Just because it won't fit. I see that your `body` is set to have a max-width of 85%. If that 85% translates into 700px and your video+widget add up 900px, it will send your widget down because it's on the right side.

Comment: Changing the body's width helped me as i was able to make the widget wider so it looks a bit better now but even then i am not able to change the height of the widget to be 500px which is what i want it to be. I've tried inline and inline-block now. also how do i create some space between the video and widget, like 3-4 cm would be enough. THANKS by the way

Comment: @m.hussain I see, alright. I wish I had control of your site to do it for you to be honest so I can see the output (laughs). All I can say is you have to go to https://twitter.com/settings/widgets and change your height in there. It's the best way.

Comment: Yh that would be amazing haha. Thanks for all your help mate. i appreciate its much no-one else helps his much. Do you know how i can create some space between the video and widget?

Comment: @m.hussain You are very welcome, by the way (sorry if I didn't say it before, I'm focused on solving the issue). You can add a margin (but that will increase the YouTube+Widget width). Let's say a `margin-right` on YouTube or a `margin-left` on Widget.

Comment: oh well, looks like we can't solve everything haha (i know i shouldn't be saying this as a coder) by the ay the margin's aren't making a difference even though I've tried them on both the widget and video. no worries mate, i tried padding instead and it works now. thanks for all your help

Comment: @m.hussain Looking at your page, I found that the Twitter iframe created by the script returns a class `twitter-timeline` with the height set to 600px. I thought that the Twitter feed was yours, that's why I was telling you to change it there. Also, I didn't notice we were talking about a div wrapping the actual widget. The solution is to do `.twitter-timeline { height: 503px; }` (**yes, 503, because reasons.**). You can now forget about the `#twitter` having a height.

Answer (score 0):

Try this codes.

twitter frame having max-width="520" that is a boundary.portfolia images supported responsive also.

MAKE IT COOL,WE LOVE OUR CODING.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <head>
  <title>Muhammed's Webpage</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css">
  <script src="homepage.js"></script>

  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:500,700,800italic,600|Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 </head>

 <div class="mainlogo">

  <body>Muhammed's 
   <br>Webpage</body>

  </div>

   <div id="body">

    <nav>
      <ul>

        <li><a href="#BasicInfo"> BASIC INFORMATION </a></li>
        <li><a href="#CurriculumVitae"> CURRICULUM VITAE </a></li>
        <li><a href="#Portfolio"> PORTFOLIO </a></li>
        <li><a href="#Report"> REPORT </a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="yt">
      <iframe  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/nKIu9yen5nc">
      </iframe>
    </div>

   <div id = "twitter">
    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/applenws" data-widget-id="674678491141570560">Tweets by @applenws</a>
   </div>

    <div class="content" id="Basic Information">
      <h3 class="contentbox"> <u>Basic Information</u> </h3>
      <p>
        <br>Name: Muhammed Hussain 
        <br>Age: 18 
        <br>Contact Number: 07711909673
        <br>E-mail: Mhuss055@gold.ac.uk
        <br>Occupation: Student of Goldsmiths, University of London
        <br>Hobbies & Interests: Playing on my ps4 and outdoor tennis
        <br>
        <br>  
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content" id="Curriculum Vitae">
      <h3 class="contentbox"> <u>Curriculum Vitae</u> </h3>
      <p>
        <br><u>Jun 2015 - Currently Employed</u> : <b>Harrods - Operations Assistant</b> 
        <br>Responsible for ensuring all daily administrative tasks are met within time schedule
        <br>Worked with colleagues to sustain a world class service of luxury goods, through providing an excellent service while working in a team environment and focusing on customer service
        <br>Proactive use of CCA and SAP software on a regular basis, in order to deal with online orders.
        <br>
        <br><u>Jun 2014 - Sep 2014</u> : <b>Direct Accountancy - Accounts Assistant</b>
        <br>Assisted Account Manager through creating invoices and sending to customers using SAGE software
        <br>Made and arranged invoices occasionally for customers, and ensured these were sent out promptly upon receiving the order.
        <br>
        <br>
        <u>Skills Gained:</u>
        <br>Communication - Established rapport and resolved queries within pressurised customer service environments
        <br>Teamwork - Motivated and developed colleagues to work effectively
        <br>Leadership - Showed leadership qualities when delivering end of unit presentations at Sixth form 
        <br>
        <br> 
      <p>
    </div>

    <div class="content" id="Portfolio" style="height:250px">
      <h3 class="contentbox"> <u>Portfolio</u> </h3>
      <p>
        <br>Here im going to include some images and use css to make them interactive and exciting
        <br>
        <br>
      </p>

      <ul class="portfolioimg" style="">
         <li><img src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/img/devices.png" alt="Responsive across devices" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li><img src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/img/devices.png" alt="Responsive across devices" class="img-responsive"></li>
         <li><img src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/img/devices.png" alt="Responsive across devices" class="img-responsive"></li>

      </ul>

    </div>


    <div class="content" id="Report">
      <h3 class="contentbox"> <u>Report</u> </h3>
      <p>
        <br>Here im going to state why i did what i did in detail
      <p>
        <br>
    </div>

        <br>
        <br>

  </body>

</html>


<style>
body{
  background-color:gray;
}


.portfolioimg {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
     margin: 30px auto 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: static !important;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1000px;
    background-color:transparent;
}
.portfolioimg > li {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: medium none !important;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
.portfolioimg > li img{
  width:200px;
  }

#body {


    margin: auto;
    max-width: 85%; 
    font-family: 'Exo 2', Times, serif;
    color: black;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.mainlogo {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: 'Montserrat' , Times, serif;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
nav {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;  
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 4%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    max-width: 85%;

}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 20px;
}
li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
}

li:first-child {
    border-left: 2px solid black;
}
li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 36px 40px; 
    text-decoration: underline; 
    font-family: 'Montserrat', Times, serif;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #aaa ;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color: #C2E5E5;
    color: black; 
}

.yt {
  margin-left: 53px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display:inline-block;
  height: 500px;
  width: 650px;
} 

#twitter {
  display:inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 520px;
}

.contentbox {
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color:  #C2E5E5;
}
.content {
    background-color: #C2E5E5;
}
p {
    text-indent: 3%; 
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 95%;
}

.contentbox {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', Times, serif;
    font-size: 28px;
}
</style>

<script>
!function(d,s,id){
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
    if(!d.getElementById(id)){
        js=d.createElement(s);
        js.id=id;
        js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }
}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for the help. i just tried to use your code but the problem is when i use that width it goes below the video and i want it on the same line, even when i get them to be on the same line by changing the width the height won't get any smaller, this is the dimensions I'm using for the height and width 

#twitter {
  display:inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
}